# How to delete row when use Django only templates

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I tried several options but to no avail.
How can I get the job done if I only use templates?
I want to delete the selected record with a button.
I also have an add button in the html, after the add button it shows me the base again.

All entries come with a delete button, but I can't get the job done.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name='index'),
    path("all_flat", views.all_flat, name='all_flat'),
    path("contact", views.contact, name='contact'),
    path("about", views.about, name='about'),
    path("save", views.testing, name='save'),
    #path("save/<int:pk>", views.delete, name='delete'),
]
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def testing(request):
    mydata = models.FlatModelSqlite.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.FlatSerializerSqlite(mydata, many=True)

    if request.method == "GET":

        html_save = "MyHome/save.html"
        template = loader.get_template(html_save)
        context = {
            'mymembers': serializer_class.data, 'flatP': ForecastField_all(),
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

    elif request.method == "POST":
        item_serializer = serializers.FlatSerializerSqlite(data=request.data)

        if item_serializer.is_valid():
            item_serializer.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to='save')
        else:
            er = item_serializer.errors
            html_save = "MyHome/save.html"
            template = loader.get_template(html_save)
            context = {
                'mymembers': serializer_class.data, 'flatP': ForecastField_all(),
                'errors': er,
            }
            return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


#@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
#def delete(request, pk):
#    if request.method == 'POST':
#        flat_delete = models.FlatModelSqlite.objects.get(pk=pk)
#        flat_delete.delete()
#        return HttpResponse(redirect_to='save')
```

html /save:

```
{% for x in mymembers %}
    <tr>

      <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.Address_N }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.Project_N }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.Fasi }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.Status }}</td>
      <td>
          <form method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="submit" value="Delete flat">
          </form></td>

    </tr>

  {% endfor %}
```

I tried to add a separate url, as shown in the code, I get an error: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`